# how do I repeat the codes in the function N times instead of re-typing it?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def append_sum(lst):
  new_num = (lst[-1]+lst[-2])
  lst.append(new_num)
  new_num1 = (lst[-1]+lst[-2])
  lst.append(new_num1)
  new_num2 = (lst[-1]+lst[-2])
  lst.append(new_num2)
  return lst

print(append_sum([1, 1, 2]))
```

this prints [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8]  but how do I do it N times?

And what is this "codes" actually called in coding? (I'm referring to the code that is in the function)

Comment: Seems like you have your answer. Just to note: you can define `new_num` as `sum(lst[-2:])` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that single operation `N` times just by doing:

```py
for _ in range(N):
    lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
```

A full example:

```py
def append_sum(lst, count):
    for _ in range(count):
        lst.append(lst[-1] + lst[-2])
    return lst

print(append_sum([1, 1], 10))
```

will generate:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144]
```

Comment: what is the difference between the "_" and " I"  for the  "for _ in range(count):" vs "for i in range(n):" (in the other guys comment)

Comment: @Titus: that's covered in far greater detail at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python than I could hope to do it justice in a comment.